# How do I make 'Edit Item' initiate in a picture button instead?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I have created a form on my SharePoint,

[image]

I want to set the 'Edit Details' picture button (circled in Lime Green) to do the function of the 'Edit Item' button found in the ribbon (circled in Pink).

Does anyone know how to do this or where I can find instructions on how to do it?

Many thanks in advance! :)

.

**Update**

I don't want to add a new item on the ribbon or change the 'Edit Item' option in the ribbon. Instead I want to replicate the functionality of the 'Edit Item' in the ribbon and put that functionality on my button, which I generated in InfoPath.

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEM STATEMENT (I think):**

From your description, I believe that you are wanting a user's click on the "Edit Details" button to cause the browser to navigate to the Edit Form of that particular item. If not, please clarify.

**USEFUL BACKGROUND INFO:**

Each item's Edit Form can be accessed by a specific url. Here's the basic structure of an Edit Form url:

```
https://{site}/Lists/{listname}/EditForm.aspx?ID={ID of the item}&Source={source url}
```

**SOLUTION:**

Build the url programmatically and apply it to the href property (or onClick action) of the "Edit Details" button.

You'll need to know the ID of the item. From your screen capture, you seem to be on the View Item page, so you can find the ID using the current url. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters) for help on that.

Comment: Hi, I'm not entirely sure how to get the ID of the form. The post you suggested me to look at has confused me. Can you explain to me please?

Comment: The ID of a sharepoint form is found in the URL, for instance with "EditForm.aspx?ID=47". At [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) you'll find both the most modern method of retrieving the URL parameter and fallback methods that work on all browsers.